# Blank.Items.Add("Some String Here") Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I am creating a Resting Metabolic Rate Calculator using Visual Basic. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to assign a numeric value to a string located in a combobox. I am having difficulties finding this information. Or if that is not possible how to make it so that if a person selects an item from the combobox that it's corresponding numeric value is inserted into the calculation.

```
'Populate Gender List
        cbxGender.Items.Add("Male")
        cbxGender.Items.Add("Female")

        'Populate Activity Level List
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Sitting or Lying all day")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Seated work, no exercise")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Seated work, light exercise")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Moderately physical work, no exercise")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Moderately physical work, light exercise")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Moderately physical work, heavy exercise")
        cbxActivity.Items.Add("Heavy work or Heavy Exercise")

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResults.Click
        'Create variables to hold information
        Dim intAge As Integer = CInt(intAge)
        Dim intHeight As Long = CLng(intHeight)
        Dim intWeight As Long = CLng(intWeight)
        Dim intActivity As Integer
        Dim intRMR As Long
        Dim txtResults As String

        'Test to make sure variables are compatible
        If Integer.TryParse(txtAge.Text, intAge) Then
            intAge = CInt(txtAge.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Try a number.")
        End If

        If Integer.TryParse(txtHeight.Text, CInt(intHeight)) Then
            intHeight = CInt(txtHeight.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Try a number.")
        End If

        If Integer.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, CInt(intWeight)) Then
            intWeight = CInt(txtWeight.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Try a number.")
        End If

        'Test for radio buttons
        If radLbs.Checked = True Then
            intWeight = intWeight \ CLng(2.205)
        End If

        If radIn.Checked = True Then
            intHeight = intHeight \ CInt(2.54)
        End If

        'Displays results
        txtResults.Text = "Hello, your Resting Metabolic Rate is " & intRMR & " Calories per day."

    End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be a WinForms app, right?

Comment: it's Visual Basic, but yes

Answer (score 0):

A WinForms `ComboBox` control can hold items of any `Object`. Currently, you are adding `String` values to it, but you could also use other kinds of objects, including instances of self defined classes/structures.

Suppose you create a class for combobox items like this:

```
Public Class ComboBoxItem
  Public ReadOnly Property Value As Integer
  Public ReadOnly Property Text As String

  Public Sub New(Value As Integer, Text As String)
    Me.Value = Value
    Me.Text = Text
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Text
  End Function
End Class
```

I can propose two population strategies for you here. Both have their pros and cons. It's up to you to investigate them somewhat further so that you can determine the most appropriate strategy to use in your application.

#### Strategy 1

Using the new `ComboBoxItem` class, you could add combobox items like this:

```
'Populate Gender List
cbxGender.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(1, "Male"))
cbxGender.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(2, "Female"))

'Populate Activity Level List
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(1, "Sitting or Lying all day"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(2, "Seated work, no exercise"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(3, "Seated work, light exercise"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(4, "Moderately physical work, no exercise"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(5, "Moderately physical work, light exercise"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(6, "Moderately physical work, heavy exercise"))
cbxActivity.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(7, "Heavy work or Heavy Exercise"))
```

In your `btnResults_Click` event handler, you could now get the comboboxes' values using its `SelectedItem` property like this:

```
Dim intGender As Integer = CType(cbxGender.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Value
Dim intActivity As Integer = CType(cbxActivity.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Value
```

#### Strategy 2

You could also use *Data Binding* instead. In that case, you put the `ComboBoxItem` items in collections of their own and tell the comboboxes to use those collections as their data source:

```
Dim genders As New List(Of ComboBoxItem)

genders.Add(New ComboBoxItem(1, "Male"))
genders.Add(New ComboBoxItem(2, "Female"))

cbxGender.DataSource = genders
cbxGender.DisplayMember = NameOf(ComboBoxItem.Text)
cbxGender.ValueMember = NameOf(ComboBoxItem.Value)

Dim activities As New List(Of ComboBoxItem)

activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(1, "Sitting or Lying all day"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(2, "Seated work, no exercise"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(3, "Seated work, light exercise"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(4, "Moderately physical work, no exercise"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(5, "Moderately physical work, light exercise"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(6, "Moderately physical work, heavy exercise"))
activities.Add(New ComboBoxItem(7, "Heavy work or Heavy Exercise"))

cbxActivity.DataSource = activities
cbxActivity.DisplayMember = NameOf(ComboBoxItem.Text)
cbxActivity.ValueMember = NameOf(ComboBoxItem.Value)
```

You can retrieve the selected item values the same as earlier:

```
Dim intGender As Integer = CType(cbxGender.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Value
Dim intActivity As Integer = CType(cbxActivity.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Value
```

or you could use the `SelectedValue` property of the combobox:

```
Dim intGender As Integer = CInt(cbxGender.SelectedValue)
Dim intActivity As Integer = CInt(cbxActivity.SelectedValue)
```